# I cant deserialize latitude and longitude in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am using .NET Core with an API project to deserialize JSON received to an object, but I can't; I get errors all the time.

When I write

```
ChevacaPackets objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChevacaPackets>(lala);
```

and I debug, the app explodes.

My Json is:

> {"applicationID":"2","applicationName":"CHEVACA_APP","deviceName":"Heltec_Lora_GPS_30","devEUI":"AL5dvw2Et0k=","rxInfo":[],"txInfo":{"frequency":902700000,"modulation":"LORA","loRaModulationInfo":{"bandwidth":125,"spreadingFactor":10,"codeRate":"4/5","polarizationInversion":false}},"adr":true,"dr":0,"fCnt":12409,"fPort":2,"data":"TmioWArY/8gT","objectJSON":"{"alt":-56,"hdop":1.9,"info":"Buena
> senal.","lat":-34.86879973821638,"lon":-56.190426122571594}","tags":{},"confirmedUplink":true,"devAddr":"ACwaOQ=="}

```
public class ChevacaPackets
{
    public string applicationID { get; set; }
    public string applicationName { get; set; }
    public string deviceName { get; set; }
    public string devEUI { get; set; }
    //public string rxInfo { get; set; }
 
    public bool adr { get; set; }
    public int dr { get; set; }
    public int fCnt { get; set; }
    public int fPort { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
         
    public objetoJSON objectJSON { get; set; }
         
    //public string tags { get; set; }
    public bool confirmedUplink { get; set; }
    public string devAddr { get; set; }
}    
 
public class objetoJSON
{
    public int alt { get; set; }
    public decimal hdop { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
    public decimal lat { get; set; }
    public decimal lon { get; set; }             
}
```

Comment: what error do you get exactly? Can you show us the complet exception?

Comment: That "JSON" is malformed, specifically the `objectJSON`. Contact whoever is providing that to you and tell them to fix their broken code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the quotes before the objectJSON....

here is my code....

> public IActionResult Post( JsonDocument objectJSON )
> {
> string jeti = objectJSON.RootElement.ToString();
> string jet=Regex.Unescape(jeti);
> jet= jet.Replace(""{", "{");
> jet= jet.Replace("}"", "}");
>
> ```
>         try
>         {
>             ChevacaPackets objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChevacaPackets>(jet);
>         
>             Contexto.ChevacaPackets.Add(objeto);
>             Contexto.SaveChanges();
>             return Ok();
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(e);
>             throw;
>         }
>
>         return BadRequest();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The objectJSON field is not JSON at all. The quotes are misplaced.

```
{
"applicationID": "2",
"applicationName": "CHEVACA_APP",
"deviceName": "Heltec_Lora_GPS_30",
"devEUI": "AL5dvw2Et0k=",
"rxInfo": [],
"txInfo": {
    "frequency": 902700000,
    "modulation": "LORA",
    "loRaModulationInfo": {
        "bandwidth": 125,
        "spreadingFactor": 10,
        "codeRate": "4/5",
        "polarizationInversion": false
    }
},
"adr": true,
"dr": 0,
"fCnt": 12409,
"fPort": 2,
"data": "TmioWArY/8gT",
"objectJSON": "{" alt ":-56," hdop ":1.9," info ":" Buena senal."," lat ":-34.86879973821638," lon ":-56.190426122571594}",
"tags": {},
"confirmedUplink": true,
"devAddr": "ACwaOQ==" 
}
```

You need to correct the malformed objectJSON property. The curly brackets are what denote an object in JSON. They should not be enclosed by strings. The corrected object property should be:

```
"objectJSON": { "alt":-56, "hdop":1.9, "info": "Buena senal.", "lat": -34.86879973821638, "lon": -56.190426122571594 },
```

Comment: This is only tabs....

I deserialized the whole json to the object ChevacaPackets without the objectJSON that is inside and works fine, the problem is when i include the objectJSON....

Comment: Right, because the value of objectJSON is malformed.

Comment: in which part is wrong? i am reading the whole json and i dont find the malformed part

Comment: I already demonstrated which part is wrong. Look carefully at the value of objectJSON. You have double quotes around the open brace. I posted the correct value for objectJSON.

Comment: Well, I posted the corrected syntax for objectJSON that would allow the de-serialization to work. Where are you obtaining the JSON from? Do you control the code that creates that JSON?